# I'm having trouble drawing a maple leaf in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Hey So I am trying to draw a Canadian Flag with python turtle but I am a beginner and I am having trouble drawing a maple leaf. Here is my code for the rectangles which I managed to do but Im stuck on the leaf so I was wondering if anyone could explain it in simple terms. Here is the code I have to draw the 2 red sides

```
import turtle 
t = turtle.Turtle()

def rectangle1(): 
 t.color('red')
 t.begin_fill()
 for i in range(2): 
  t.forward(100)
  t.right(90)
  t.forward(250)
  t.right(90)
 t.end_fill()
rectangle1()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#MapleLeaf-Modifiable by USA
# This will do "black" & "red", plus "white" & "blue" for Toronto, may God bless you all.

import turtle

def MapleLeaf(x=None, y=None):
    if x == None:
        x=0
    if y == None:
        y=0


    s = float(input("Please enter scale factor ? "))

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(1*s,-3*s)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.goto(5*s,-4*s)
    turtle.goto(4*s,-3*s)
    turtle.goto(9*s,1*s)
    turtle.goto(7*s,2*s)
    turtle.goto(8*s,5*s)
    turtle.goto(5*s,4*s)
    turtle.goto(5*s,5*s)
    turtle.goto(3*s,4*s)
    turtle.goto(4*s,9*s)
    turtle.goto(2*s,7*s)
    turtle.goto(0*s,10*s)
    turtle.goto(-2*s,7*s)
    turtle.goto(-4*s,8*s)
    turtle.goto(-3*s,3*s)
    turtle.goto(-5*s,6*s)
    turtle.goto(-5*s,4*s)
    turtle.goto(-8*s,5*s)
    turtle.goto(-7*s,2*s)
    turtle.goto(-9*s,1*s)
    turtle.goto(-4*s,-3*s)
    turtle.goto(-5*s,-4*s)
    turtle.goto(0*s,-3*s)
    turtle.goto(2*s,-7*s)
    turtle.goto(2*s,-6*s)
    turtle.goto(1*s,-3*s)
    turtle.hideturtle()




pnc = input("Please enter MapleLeaf boarder color ? ")
turtle.pencolor(pnc) # pen color optional
mlc = input("Please enter MapleLeaf color ? ")
turtle.fillcolor(mlc)# Main MapleLeaf Color Optional
turtle.begin_fill()
MapleLeaf(0,0)
turtle.end_fill()
turtle.done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Array of points solution:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()


def draw_leaf(size):
    leaf_points = [[0, 7], [-1.2, 4.4], [-3, 5], [-2, 1],
                   [-4, 3], [-4.3, 1.5], [-7, 2.5], [-5.5, 0],
                   [-7, -1], [-3.3, -3.4], [-4, -5], [-0.2, -4.2],
                   [-0.2, -8], [0.2, -8], [0.2, -4.2], [4, -5],
                   [3.3, -3.4], [7, -1], [5.5, 0], [7, 2.5],
                   [4.3, 1.5], [4, 3], [2, 1], [3, 5],
                   [1.2, 4.4], [0, 7]]
    t.color('red')
    t.begin_fill()
    for (x, y) in leaf_points:
        t.goto(x * size, y * size)
    t.end_fill()


draw_leaf(size=30)
```